# Passwordless root login with ssh tectia denied by policy

Tags: ssh, root

I need to setup passwordless root access with ssh tectia. I've done the following:

- created keypair via ssh-keygen as usual
- copied private key to `*source_host*:/etc/opt/SSHtectia/keys/root` . Also i created file `/etc/opt/SSHtectia/keys/root/identification` and specified private key there.
- copied public key to `*target_host*:/etc/opt/SSHtectia/keys/root` . Also i created file `/etc/opt/SSHtectia/keys/root/authorization` and specified public key there.

When tried to login, i see that key was accepted, but login was denied

```
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 400 Connect, Policy name: connection, Src: sourcehost.my.domain,sourcehost, Src IP: x.x.7.131, Dst IFace: default, Dst IP: x.x.7.151, Src Port: 38158, Dst Port: 22, Ver: SSH-2.0-6.3.8.79 SSH Secure Shell, Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 1002 Algorithm_negotiation_success, "kex_algorithm=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, hostkey_algorithm=ssh-rsa, cipher=aes128-cbc/aes128-cbc, mac=hmac-sha1/hmac-sha1, compression=none/none", Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 703 Auth_methods_available, Username: root, Auth methods: publickey, Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 707 Publickey_auth_success, Username: root, Algorithm: publickey, "The user's public key matched the key (/etc/opt/SSHtectia/keys/root/authorized_11.pub, fingerprint xozel-pezer-sacok-vunud-horim-ropuc-milaf-nobip-setuc-zedar-boxex/bd7afcbc846e24252f8b29181f3940ac771f49b0) in the user's authorization file (/etc/opt/SSHtectia/keys/root/authorization)", Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 700 Auth_method_success, Username: root, Auth method: publickey, Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 702 Auth_methods_completed, Username: root, Auth methods: publickey, Src IP: x.x.7.131, Src Port: 38158, Ver: SSH-2.0-6.3.8.79 SSH Secure Shell, Session-Id: 288135 
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 410 Login_success, Username: root, Src: sourcehost.my.domain,sourcehost, Src IP: x.x.7.131, Dst IFace: default, Dst IP: x.x.7.151, Src Port: 38158, Dst Port: 22, Ver: SSH-2.0-6.3.8.79 SSH Secure Shell, Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 420 Session_channel_open, Username: root, Error: Denied by policy, Command: shell, Sub ID: 0, Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 421 Session_channel_close, Username: root, Sub ID: 0, Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 412 Logout, Username: root, Reason: By application, Src: sourcehost.my.domain,sourcehost, Src IP: x.x.7.131, Dst IFace: default, Dst IP: x.x.7.151, Src Port: 38158, Dst Port: 22, "Connection discarded by broker, Remote Disconnect", Session-Id: 288135
    Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 402 Disconnect, Reason: By application, Src: sourcehost.my.domain,sourcehost, Src IP: x.x.7.131, Dst IFace: default, Dst IP: x.x.7.151, Src Port: 38158, Dst Port: 22, "Connection discarded by broker, Remote Disconnect", Session-Id: 288135
```

[ssh-broker-config.xml](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2HEO)

[ssh-server-config.xml](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2HEQ)

Non-root passwordless logins are working fine.

Comment: What if you set in ssh-server-config.xml, for rule group="admins", `terminal action="allow"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you are getting:

```
Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 410 Login_success, Username: root, Src: sourcehost.my.domain,sourcehost, Src IP: x.x.7.131, Dst IFace: default, Dst IP: x.x.7.151, Src Port: 38158, Dst Port: 22, Ver: SSH-2.0-6.3.8.79 SSH Secure Shell, Session-Id: 288135
Feb 25 11:52:42 targethost ssh-server-g3: 420 Session_channel_open, Username: root, Error: Denied by policy, Command: shell, Sub ID: 0, Session-Id: 288135
```

It seems the authentication works but then the user is denied a shell or terminal access.

This is because in the rule group for admins you have: `terminal action="deny"`.

You need to change the `terminal action` to "allow"`in the ssh-server-config.xml for`rule group="admins"`.

```
<rule group="admins" idle-timeout="0" print-motd="no">
      <environment allowed-case-sensitive="TERM,PATH,TZ,LANG,LC_*" />
      <terminal action="allow" />
      <subsystem type="sftp" action="allow" application="sft-server-g3" />
      <command action="allow" />
      <tunnel-agent action="deny" />
      <tunnel-x11 action="deny" />
      <tunnel-local action="deny" />
      <tunnel-remote action="deny" />
    </rule>
```

As mentioned in [Configuration Settings in ssh-server-config.xml](https://support.ssh.com/manuals/clientserver-unix-eval/60/cscquick-xmlconfig.html), the user has no access to a command shell when terminal access is denied.

> **Restricting Terminal Access**
>
> You can restrict terminal access so that it is allowed only for users 
>   in group admin. To disable terminal access from everyone else, make the 
>   following settings in the ssh-server-config.xml file, in the services 
>   block:

```
<rule group="admin">
      <terminal action="allow" />
    ...
    </rule>

    <rule group="SFTP-users">
      <terminal action="deny" />
    ...
    </rule>

    <rule>
      <terminal action="deny" />
    ...
    </rule>
```

> This setting denies also X11 and agent forwarding and *shell commands*
>   for the specified group (unless some commands are explicitly allowed).
>
> *The users will be able to use SFTP and other subsystems defined in the
>   SSH Tectia Server configuration. Any other "exec" and "shell" requests
>   will be denied for the users.* This includes forced commands with
>   public keys and the legacy-style password changing when performed as a
>   forced command.